# sql pulling data in in certain rows but not others

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

table 1 looks like this:

```
filekey  hourstype   hours
 123        1          40
 123        2           5
 123        3           6
 123        4           7
 123        5           8
```

needed output should look like this:

```
filekey   hours1    hours2    otherhourstype otherhourstotal
 123        40        5          ''             ''
 123        ''        ''         3              6
 123        ''        ''         4              7
 123        ''        ''         5              8
```

hours1 and hours2 occupy the same row, all other hours occupy their own row

there is one other possible format that can work:

```
filekey   hours1    hours2    difhrstype difhrstotal  difhourstype difhrstotal
 123        40        5          3             6         4              7
```

in this scenario start with lowest hours type, then total extended through columns instead of rows with one row per filekey.  I'm not sure how to make this one happen either.  especially because there can be up to 8 hourstypes each of which may or may not exist for a given filekey

Comment: Check out the PIVOT command

Comment: I don't think PIVOT will work, but UNION will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for scenario 1:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(filekey INT, hourstype INT, [hours] INT)

INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES
(123,1,40)
,(123,2,5)
,(123,3,6)
,(123,4,7)
,(123,5,8)

SELECT
    T.filekey
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN hourstype = 1 THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) AS hours1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN hourstype = 2 THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) AS hours2
    ,CASE WHEN hourstype > 2 THEN [hourstype] ELSE 0 END AS otherhourstype
    ,CASE WHEN hourstype > 2 THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END AS otherhourstotal
FROM
    #TMP T
GROUP BY
    T.filekey
    ,CASE WHEN hourstype > 2 THEN [hourstype] ELSE 0 END 
    ,CASE WHEN hourstype > 2 THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION a query that will produce the first row over a query that will produce the other three rows.

Hard-code the NULLs (or blanks or whatever you want) for the unused columns in each query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 select 
    pivottable.filekey,
    [1] as hours1,
    [2] as hours2,
    [3] as hours3,
    [4] as hours4,
    [5] as hours5,
    [6] as hours6,
    [7] as hours7,
    [8] as hours8
 from table1
 PIVOT (
 sum(hours)
 FOR hourstype IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]) 
 ) as pivottable
```